# Undo "Hidden history for new members" in Telegram group

Tags: telegram, telethon

Is there a way to revoke hidden history for **existing** members of a private Telegram group?

Right now, if a new member joins while hidden history is turned ON, there is no way to re-enable it back for them (for example after they have solved a captcha). Strangely enough, if the same member is kicked out, hidden history gets disabled and they rejoin, they **still** cannot see the historical messages.

I am looking for a solution to this using either the official API or the `telethon` wrapper (an endpoint would suffice).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `TogglePreHistoryHiddenRequest` function.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
api_id = 121212
api_hash = "97dsakn421hdsapogjdmaewod"
with TelegramClient("anon", api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.TogglePreHistoryHiddenRequest(
        channel='username',
        enabled=False
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

If `enabled` is `False`, the chat for new members is visible. Otherwise is hidden.

Comment: thanks! I don't think this will "revoke hidden history for existing member" (keyword here is "existing") as I asked in the OP.  Also I think you should hide your `api_id` and `api_hash` because you posted it in your answer :)

Comment: The api id and the api hash are faked. Of course, I would never show my API data.

Comment: Sorry, I tried using this method and it will revoke the hidden chat history.